# Easy UICollectionView Custom Layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I want to create a custom layout which should look like the picture here: [Custom Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z0nMR.jpg)

I found a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich (https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) which does more or less the same but it was to complicated for me so I wasn't able to shift this to my needs.

I just need the easy layout, and I also know the size for my cells, I don't have to calculate them.
Could anyone please help me.

Comment: This layout is Flow Layout so use delegate method - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{  return CGSizeMake(50, 50); } and pass size based on indexPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
```

of `UICollectionViewDataSource` create a `switch` for the variable `indexPath.row` and set the size of the cell:

```
cell.frame = CGMake(height: myHeight; width: myWidth)
```